# WebDriver browser selection

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I want to create method that start using 1 of the browsers (IE, Chrome, FireFox) and if one of them not exist then move to the other browser?
For exemple start with FF and if not exist then move to Chrome and if not exist then move to IE and if its also don't exist then assert.

Answer (score 0):

Write one utility method that instantiate the driver object in try catch block and returns the first available driver(FF/IE/Chrome) object; if first one doesn't exists code will try to instantiate 2nd browser and so on...

Here is the sample code structure:

```
    private WebDriver getDriver(){  
        WebDriver driver = null;
    try{
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(); 
        return driver;
    } catch (Exception e){}

    try{
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(); 
        return driver;
    } catch (Exception e){}
    try{
        driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
        return driver;
    } catch (Exception e){}

    return driver;
    }

    //Then call the getDriver method and assert not equal to null.

    WebDriver driver = getDriver();
    Assert.assertNotNull(driver);

    //Continue with your tests...
```

Comment: Thanks, i found it very usefull